# Shimano Sora 3400 shifters with Shimano Alivio M430 rear derailleur?

Tags: shimano, shifter, derailleur-rear

I'm thinking about a touring built with just spare parts I have.

I have a rear Alivio M430 9 speed derailleur and Alivio 9 speed 11-34t cassette already. I want to have drops and Sora 3400 is the cheapest 9 speed road shifters I could find. I don't think there is a difference between the cog spacing between road and MTB so it should work if my assumption is true.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with 9-speed this sort of combination works because Shimano mountain and road rear derailleur actuation was the same until mountain 10 came out.

Answer (score 1):

Yss, this setup will work.

You are correct that the sprocket spacing is the same for Shimano (and SRAM) road and mountain 9 speed systems.

Shimano road up to 10 speed and mountain up to 9 speed derailleurs used the same *cable actuation ratio* (ratio of how much cable is pulled by the shifter to how far the derailleur cage moves laterally). What this means is you can actually use *any* of those derailleurs as long as the shifter matches the cassette (and the derailleur has capacity for the size of the cassette of course).